# Look up values in a string SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic

I have a table with values separated by commas e.g.

Impacted Areas
01,05,06,07

These values relate to an impacted area in a dimension table

What is the best way to look up the definition of the area

The table has multiple columns in this format which require look up, so I need the best way to repeat this multiple times within one query.

Comment: What is the relationship between the 'definition of the area' and your comma separated values?  Do the values represent corners of a square?  E.g. `Impacted Areas {top-left},{bottom-left},{top-right},{bottom-right}`?

Comment: Please  normalize your schema. The sooner  the better.

Comment: By far the best way to deal with this is adhere to 1NF and not store multiple values in a single column like this.

Comment: What version of SQL? 2016+ has a string_split() function that might be of use. And if you're <2016, you could probably use that logic to build a TVF for the JOIN.

Comment: Do you have SQL Server 2016+? If so, string_split, otherwise there is SQL that will loop through the string and get a list of areas, however it has scaling issues if you need to look through multiple strings as it loops for each string.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at the SQL like operator

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

you could potentially search for something like:

SELECT * FROM table where Areas like '%,10,%'

will find any areas containing the string ',10,'

Comment: What if 10 is the first or last value? This just isn't a solution that is workable.